# convert character to numeric values (with 2 types of numeric values) using r

Tags: r, numeric

I have a variable that should be numeric but is a character, this variable has two types of numeric values, when I convert them to numeric one is not recognized as a number:

```
num <-c("3,98E+03", "3,98E+03","0.003382932", "5,22E+02", "0.005464587")
as.numeric(num)
NAs introduced by coercion[1]          NA          NA 0.003382932          NA 0.005464587
```

I don't want to have NA introduced.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the `,` with `.` using `sub`:

```
as.numeric(sub(",", ".", num, fixed = TRUE))
#[1] 3.980000e+03 3.980000e+03 3.382932e-03 5.220000e+02 5.464587e-03
```

Answer (score 1):

The `readr` package has helpful functions to parse numbers from a string which may be more generalisable. `string_replace()` also replaces the `,` with a `.` similar to answer by @GKi

```
library(stringr)
library(readr)

parse_number(str_replace(num, ",", "."))
```